# drupal xmlrpc problem with user.login redirect

Tags: drupal, redirect, authentication, xml-rpc

I'm building an external app in PHP outside of Drupal and am building a login form to log into some Drupal sites with it using xmlrpc service that Drupal provides. The xmlrpc user.login would not work. I realized I had an action and a trigger set up In Drupal so when a user logs in, it sends them to a welcome page.
I disabled the trigger and now my user.login xmlrpc connection works!
The problem is, I need that redirect working. Is there a way to fix this? Maybe xmlrpc server can detect if somone is logging in with xmlrpc and not do the triggers?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realized I had an action and a trigger set up so when a user logs in, it sends them to a welcome page.
I disable the trigger and now my user.login xmlrpc connection works!
The problem is, I need that redirect working. So is there a way to fix this?
**Update:** 
Temporary solution until triggers or services gets fixed:
I had to disable my trigger and do the redirect in a custom module instead. My module is called "form_mods"

```
function form_mods_user ( $op ){
    if ( $op == "login" ){
    $_REQUEST['destination'] = 'welcome';
    }
}
```